# Add my business and current Google+ page to Google places

Tags: google-plus, google-my-business

I have a Google place page I do not want to erase or migrate, it contains YouTube videos with insights, posts, photos etc.

When I try to add my business in [Google Places](http://places.google.com), it automatically creates a new Google+ page which I do not want.

Is there a way to attach my current Google+ page to a specific address and verify it?